# Dynamically name ID in number_field_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

***View***

```
<% @foo.each do |foo| %>
  <%= number_field_tag 'foo-number', foo.id %>
<% end %>
```

The first value passed to number_field_tag sets the ID for the HTML input field. When passing in `'foo number'` the `input ID = foo-number`. I would like to dynamically name this div along the lines of:

```
<%= number_field_tag 'foo-number-#{foo.id}', foo.id %>
```

where `#{foo.id}` injects the id of foo into the ID name, thereby dynamically naming each `number_field_tag`.

At this stage I can go with a fully static naming convention using `foo-number`, as shown in my example at the very top, or a fully dynamic naming convention, where I only use `foo.id`, `<%= number_field_tag foo.id, foo.id %>`. I am not able to create the hybrid, where the first section of the `ID name` is static and the back of the Id is dynamically named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right with the solution, you just need to use double quotes sp the string interpolation works

```
<%= number_field_tag "foo-number-#{foo.id}", foo.id %>
```